# Hybris Backoffice's category synchronization is missing some options present on hmc

Tags: synchronization, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

On Hmc when attempting to synchronize a category, I can see 2 options in the synchroniation wizzard:

`incl. subcategories` and `incl. products.`

When attempting to synchronize the category on backoffice I can't find those 2 options. Is there a way to enable it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Hybris version are you using?

Comment: The version is 6.6

Comment: These properties are available in the `synchronizecatalogversionwizard` but I can't find the usage for this wizard....

Comment: I could not found synchronizecatalogversionwizard  for backofice. But there is one for the hmc context.